# Accessing a photo from another serves using html

Tags: html

I found a photo in www.w3schools.com. In that server i can access it by using simple html tag. It's src = "smiley.gif". I want to access the photo in www.practiseboard.com. I have no clue how to do that. Please help.

Comment: And i don't want to download it. I just want to access a photo directly from another server.

Comment: Use the full URL of the image in the `img src`.

Comment: <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/smiley.gif" alt="W3Schools.com" style="width:104px;height:142px;">,  give the complete url

Comment: I tried using full link in src. Please give me an example.

Comment: @ParadoxNafi: Give an example of what you tried and how it failed.  The internet is literally *full* of examples of how to do this.  Including several on this very page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the image and copy it URL:

```
Chrome: Copy image URL

Safari: Copy image address

Firefox: Copy image location
```

Then use that URL in your img tag.

```
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" alt="Smile">
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/4v1az6rx/

Answer (score 0):

Use full URL and dont forget `http://`

if the target site prevents hotlink, you can not display it inside your website.

```
<img src="http://www.practiseboard.com/smiley.gif">
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you are looking for!

```
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg"; alt="W3Schools.com" />
```

demo : http://www.practiceboard.com/4fbfc9fc

replace **src** with full url of the image as **Ali** said!